# Dropzone uploadMultiple with Java Struts, FileUploadInterceptor of File Name and Content Type not being called?

Tags: java, file, dropzone

I am using dropzone with Java Struts2. Before adding uploadMultiple:true to dropzone, server side working properly, i.e. getter and setter of File, FileName, and ContentType will be called accordingly. However after adding uploadMultiple:true, only the getter and setter of File are being called by the Struts interceptor.

I tried to change the param name and following these two website to do that, but no luck.
https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload-interceptor.html
https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-upload-multiple-files-example/

//My JS

```
    $("form#addrBookDropzone").dropzone(
        {
            url: "uploadData",
            maxFilesize: maxFileSize,
            maxFiles: 10,
            acceptedFiles: ".csv",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple:true,
            parallelUploads: 10,
            paramName:'csvFile',
            init: function (e) {
                abDropzone = this;  
                abDropzone.processQueue();
            },
            success: function(file, response){
                retrieveCsvTransition();
            }

        }
    );
```

//My Java

public class FileProcessor extends ActionSupport{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -234712913575630908L;
public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileProcessor.class);
private String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private List<File> csvFile = new ArrayList<File>(); 
private List<String> csvFileContentType = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> csvFileFileName = new ArrayList<String>();
private Set<TblCsvTransition> csvData = new HashSet<TblCsvTransition>(0);
private AbstractMap<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<String, File>(0);



public List<File> getCsvFile() {
    return csvFile;
}

public void setCsvFile(List<File> csvFile) {
    this.csvFile = csvFile;
}

public List<String> getCsvFileContentType() {
    return csvFileContentType;
}

public void setCsvFileContentType(List<String> csvFileContentType) {
    this.csvFileContentType = csvFileContentType;
}

public List<String> getCsvFileFileName() {
    return csvFileFileName;
}

public void setCsvFileFileName(List<String> csvFileFileName) {
    this.csvFileFileName = csvFileFileName;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure why struts not passing file names, in the end I can only comment out parallelUploads and passing the file names as param